# How can I group data while fetching from mongodb using go?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a collection named "myplace" It has the following fileds place_name, city, latitude, longitude.

Doc format

```
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("544a2147785b707b340ed6c7"),
      "latitude" : 12.36547,
      "longitude" : 1.235689,
      "place_name" : "some_place",
      "city" : "City1"
}
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("544a2147785b707b340ed6c7"),
      "latitude" : 12.36547,
      "longitude" : 1.235689,
      "place_name" : "some_place",
      "city" : "City3"
}
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("544a2147785b707b340ed6c7"),
      "latitude" : 12.36547,
      "longitude" : 1.235689,
      "place_name" : "some_place",
      "city" : "City1"
 }
 {
      "_id" : ObjectId("544a2147785b707b340ed6c7"),
      "latitude" : 12.36547,
      "longitude" : 1.235689,
      "place_name" : "some_place",
      "city" : "City2"
}
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("544a2147785b707b340ed6c7"),
      "latitude" : 12.36547,
      "longitude" : 1.235689,
      "place_name" : "some_place",
      "city" : "City2"
}
```

How can I group the data with same city? Meaning I need array of json result first array should contain all the data which having city1 second array conatins all the data which having city2 and so on

Comment: Since you are anyway fetching all the data, what about `myplace.Find(nil).Iter()` and do the grouping in Go?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in Mongo itself more easily in my opinion. Use the aggregation framework.

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([{$group:{_id: "$city", details:{$push: {latitude:  "$latitude",  longitude: "$longitude", place_name:"$place_name"}}}}])
```

I think this should work, I can't actually try it at the moment at work. hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mgo, a simple sort should do the trick. Here we search first by city and then by name:

```
query1 := collection.Find(nil).Sort("city", "place_name")
```